# Should I say "what is beautiful in/at this thing"?

Tags: prepositions

If I want to ask about the beauty of something, what is the correct option between the following two:

> "what is beautiful **at** this"?
>
> "what is beautiful **in** this"?

The meaning is like "why do you think it's nice"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Neither** of the options are in casual use. Though you may *occasionally* come across "in" in poetic use.

The best word to use here is **about**.

> What is beautiful **about** this?

Other examples:

> What's amazing about France?
>
> What's crazy about it?
>
> What's stupid about that decision?
>
> What's funny about what Bernie said?

Watch out for "wrong":

> What's *wrong* **with** you?

A more idiomatic construction would be:

> Why do you think this is beautiful?
>
> Where is the beauty in this? (*where is the (noun) in this*; you are asking how a noun counterpart to the adjective (e.g. "beauty" for "beautiful") is present.)

Comment: I've upvoted, but I'd like to quibble: "what is beautiful **in** this" is a more poetic, but still viable alternative IMO.

Comment: When using "in" relative to beauty, there is a metaphoric spatial relationship.  When inquiring about the beauty *in* something, it would be more appropriate to ask "Where is the beauty in this?"

Comment: @Dr.Funk That's a different construction entirely.

Comment: ...hence why it appears in the comments section.

Comment: Given that this section of StackExchange is devoted to helping people learn English, it is generally helpful to provide examples of alternative ways of saying things.

Comment: I added that alternate. It's pretty valid.